# Is it possible to write at virtual 0x0 on a classical OS?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, ld, virtual-memory

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question right, but I'm wondering if it's possible for a C or ASM program to write at the virtual adress 0x0 ?

I know the kernel don't allow write/read at virtual 0x0, but I'm wondering if there's some strange way to do this. Using maybe a flag for ld or gcc that I don't know about ?

The settings are as follow  :

- Computer running Linux on x86-64
- Can use root if necessary

Comment: The page containing address zero is commonly unmapped or mapped with no accesss, but there are system calls to request mapping and to change the protection.

Comment: See also: [allocating address zero on Linux with mmap fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63790813/555045)

Comment: Depends on the OS. On Linux? No.

Comment: What's a "classical OS"? Hopefully it's not a colloquialism for ancient Roman or Greek operating systems. Maybe [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846461/how-does-mmap-page-zero-personality-flag-work) will be helpful.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: The comment above yours refers to a question with an answer saying it can be done on Linux and saying how. What is your basis for claiming it cannot be done?

Comment: BTW I went ahead and ran the code for the linked question on Xubuntu (a relatively normal distro, I suppose?) and it does in fact work. By that I mean when I run it as root, of course, not as regular user. I even added an actual dereference of the null address and that worked too. But I imagine none of this is convincing for the naysayers, for them I recommend that they just try it themselves.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well you can set up Linux to do whatever you want of course. I didn't know one only needs to change a config variable to enable this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for the ressource, the mmap method effectively works, I was not aware of this method ! If you post this as an answer I can accept it for others to see ? (I'm pretty new to SO)

Comment: The HP-UX linker has an option (`-Z`) to map a zero page at address zero. I can't remember whether that's a writeable page or read-only.

Comment: @harold: Interesting, I hadn't realized root bypassed `vm.mmap_min_addr`, but I tested on my system with `sudo strace ./a.out` and it does indeed make mmap(0, MAP_FIXED) succeed where it doesn't without `sudo`.  Without `sudo`, the failure reason is `EPERM`, so it makes some sense that elevated permissions / capabilities would help.  I'm using x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux with kernel 6.7.  Arch is known for not customizing upstream software too much, so in that sense is a "normal" distro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three steps are needed to do this:

1. Configure the system to permit mapping memory at address zero.  This is done by setting the [`vm.mmap_min_addr`](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr) sysctl to 0:

   ```
   sysctl vm.mmap_min_addr=0
   ```

   If you are using Wine on the system, there's a chance this sysctl is already configured as it is needed for Wine to be able to execute 16 bit code.

   An alterative to `vm.mmap_min_addr=0` is to run your process with `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`, such as by running as root like `sudo strace ./a.out`.  (`strace` lets you see the system calls it makes, so you can see `mmap` return a successful `0` rather than `(void*)-1`)
2. Establish a mapping at address 0.  To let the kernel have you write data to address 0, you need to map some memory there.  This is easily done by calling `mmap` to map some memory there or by arranging for your binary to load a segment there.

   For an `mmap` example, see *[allocating address zero on Linux with mmap fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63790813/allocating-address-zero-on-linux-with-mmap-fails)*
3. Dereference a pointer to address 0.  This can be done with C code like `*(int *)0 = 42`.
   This happens to compile to the asm we want with GCC or clang with optimization disabled<sup>1</sup>.

---

Footnote 1:
`0` is a null pointer constant in C, and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.  With optimization disabled, GCC and clang just compile to asm that stores to that address (*[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27void+foo()%7B%0A++++*(int+*)0+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar()%7B%0A++++*(volatile+int+*)0+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+hide_ub()%7B%0A++++volatile+int+*volatile+zero_ptr+%3D+0%3B++//+pointer+object+is+volatile+to+hide+null-pointer+UB%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//+pointed-to+memory+is+also+volatile+so+it+doesn!%27t+optimize+away+(because+even+though+it!%27s+volatile,+GCC+assumes+it!%27s+not+pointing+to+anything+with+a+lifetime+outside+the+function%3F++Seems+like+a+bug,+a+debugger+could+have+modified+the+pointer+object+to+point+anywhere)%0A++++*zero_ptr+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:36.276893879002834,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O1+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.389772787663844,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:60.02055498458376,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:39.97944501541624,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)*) , but clang warns *indirection of non-volatile null pointer will be deleted, not trap*, *consider using `__builtin_trap()` or qualifying pointer with 'volatile'*.  That is indeed what happens with optimization enabled.  GCC `-O2` or higher still emits a store instruction, but on x86-64 follows it with a `ud2` illegal instruction trap.

`volatile int *volatile zero_ptr = 0;` `*zero_ptr = 42;` works in GCC and clang to hide the UB from the compiler: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27void+foo()%7B%0A++++*(int+*)0+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar()%7B%0A++++*(volatile+int+*)0+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+hide_ub()%7B%0A++++volatile+int+*volatile+zero_ptr+%3D+0%3B++//+pointer+object+is+volatile+to+hide+null-pointer+UB%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//+pointed-to+memory+is+also+volatile+so+it+doesn!%27t+optimize+away+(because+even+though+it!%27s+volatile,+GCC+assumes+it!%27s+not+pointing+to+anything+with+a+lifetime+outside+the+function%3F++Seems+like+a+bug,+a+debugger+could+have+modified+the+pointer+object+to+point+anywhere)%0A++++*zero_ptr+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:36.276893879002834,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.389772787663844,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:60.02055498458376,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:39.97944501541624,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  (Making the pointer object itself `volatile` hides the fact that it's a null pointer.  Making it a pointer to `volatile int` works around a GCC bug(?) where it optimizes away the actual store, perhaps assuming that it can't be pointing to anything with a lifetime that outlasts this function.)

Comment: I don't think it's easy to use Linux `mmap()` for this, as address 0 on Linux is a null pointer, and passing a null pointer as suggested address means "let the kernel choose where to map it".

Comment: That C code is undefined behavior and it's implementation defined if that even should write to the 0 address. Compiler may or may not generate a write for that code or write somewhere else. Instead use the pointer returned by `mmap` to access the memory.

Comment: @TobySpeight Doesn't specifying `MAP_FIXED` work around that problem?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, it's not clear from the manual what happens when the two are combined.  I'd have to look at the implementation, and sadly I don't have time right now.

Comment: Indeed, this case is not covered by the manpage. But wine does require this case so it must be possible and using addr=0 and MAP_FIXED seems like the obvious solution. Easy enough to test though, just try and see if the returned address is 0 or something else.

Comment: Nice for providing an example of where accessing address zero is useful (“it is needed for Wine to be able to execute 16 bit code.”).

Comment: `0` is a null-pointer constant and dereferencing it is UB in C.  https://godbolt.org/z/hThG46P1e shows that GCC emits the store instruction we want but follows it with `ud2` (illegal instruction).  Clang doesn't emit any instructions at all for the whole function, warning that you should use `__builtin_trap()` instead, or use `volatile int *` (which does compile how we want).  You could use `volatile int *volatile zero_ptr = 0;  *zero_ptr = 0;` to hide the UB from the compiler.  (Making it pointer-to-volatile works around a GCC bug(?) where it assumes the store can be optimized away.)

Comment: Apparently `*(int*)0 = 42;` happens to work with optimization disabled, though.  Or with GCC `-O1` or lower.  https://godbolt.org/z/1eexhM5W7

Comment: Or `int *ptr = mmap(0, ...)` as a convenient way to get a runtime-variable pointer that the compiler doesn't know is going to be `0`. (OTOH that leaves room for skeptics to wonder if mmap really returned 0, which you can verify with `strace`).  And BTW, as Harold commented under the question, running as root (`sudo`) lets `mmap` work even without changing `vm.mmap_min_addr`.  I just tried it on my Arch Linux system with kernel 6.7.

Comment: The C spec does not say that address 0 cannot be accessed.  It *does* say (by a combination of provisions) that null pointer constants do not point to any object or function, and it then follows pretty directly that the behavior of evaluating `*(int *)0` is not defined.  On the other hand, the same is not necessarily true of `uintptr_t addr = 0; *(int *)addr;`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The rules of what makes and what doesn't make a null pointer are weird.  So weird in fact, that Linux has a [gadget](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/20/805) derived from them to check if something is an integer constant expression.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: According to the published Rationale, the term "Undefined Behavior" is used as a catch-all to, among other things, identify areas of "conforming language extension" where implementations may define the behavior of constructs or corner cases that aren't "officially" defined.  Specifying that any volatile reads and writes will be processed by synchronizing the states of abstract and physical machines and then instructing the physical machine to attempt the indicated access on the specified address, with whatever consequences result is a common such extension.

Comment: Of course, @supercat.  I said nothing that conflicts with that.  Nevertheless, I hold that although dereferencing a pointer to address 0 may be a reasonable thing to do, dereferencing a null pointer is semantically wrong, regardless of what actually happens.  Of course, this creates a dissonance for implementations that do not distinguish between the two.  Nevertheless, we know that a null pointer constant *always* represents a null pointer, and any pointer value that we can trace back to such a constant is also a null pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: As far as the Standard is concerned, the only thing that's "special" about a null pointer is that if two constructs are specified as producing null pointers, comparisons between the resulting pointers must report them equal to each other, and unequal to the address of any object or allocation defined by the Standard.  It is agnostic as to whether null pointers compare equal to any address that doesn't have a standard-defined meaning, or whether any pointer that happens to compare equal to a null pointer in some circumstances is "actually" a null pointer.

Comment: @supercat, I said nothing that conflicts with *that*, either.  Nevertheless, that the standard affirmatively specifies that a null pointer compares unequal to any pointer to an object or function is an excellent reason consider wrong any attempt to dereference a pointer that can be proven null based on the spec.  In particular, any attempt to dereference a pointer value that can be traced back to a null pointer constant.  That's a different question from whether a pointer value derived in some way whose semantics are not defined by the spec should be considered a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure if I'm asking the question right, but I'm wondering if it's possible for a C or ASM program to write at the virtual adress 0x0 ?

There is no rule in the C language that forbids writing to `0x0` or any other particular address.  I'm fairly certain that the same applies to most assembly languages.

In fact, C is not specified in terms of numeric addresses at all.  Pointers are the C type category for addresses, and these are not numeric.  C defines *conversions* between pointers and integers, but with the exception of null pointer constants (see below) it does not attribute any specific significance to them.

Although the C language has no concept of an address 0, the host system may very well have one.  If it does (likely), and if there is a way to form a C pointer pointing to a modifiable object residing at that address (also likely), then there is good reason to think a C program could use such a pointer to modify the object to which it points, just as it would any other valid pointer.  For example:

```
int *pointer_to_address_0 = ...;
*pointer_to_address_0 = 1;
```

---

The question may be premised in part on C null pointer constants, which have a form that could be mistaken as meaning a pointer to address 0, yet are expressly specified to not point to any object.  For example, `0` or `(void *) 0`.  But null pointer constants are a special syntactic construct, not an exercise of a more general language provision.  Even if, without basis in the spec, we take conversions from integers to pointers as mapping numeric addresses to corresponding pointers, the spec does not say that converting the value 0 to a pointer yields a null pointer generally, nor that converting a null pointer to an integer necessarily yields 0.

The question may also be premised in part on the fact that some operating environments that feature flat, numerically-addressible memory spaces take steps to make address 0 inaccessible.  Such efforts may be inspired by the observation that, at least on virtual memory systems, attempts to access very low addresses are usually erroneous.  In conjunction with some forms of pointer representation, that can contribute to attempts to dereference null pointers failing immediately and loudly, which might not otherwise be the case.  But that's not about the C language or assembly language, and even in environments exhibiting such behavior, there may be workarounds.  [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78000455/2402272) presents such a workaround for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the kernel doesn't allow you to write at virtual address 0 because that page is not mapped, so it doesn't correspond to physical memory.

When you try to read or write (in machine instructions) to the address 0, there's a trap issued by the kernel because that address doesn't exist.  That's not a requirement of the operating system.  You could perfectly map memory at that address and use it as normal.  It's the C runtime convention that considers that the `NULL` pointer should point nowhere, and so a page of memory is reserved at the bottom of the virtual address space to make the program to fail, if an access is made to it.

So, if you are going to run C programs, then it is better to follow the convention and get interrupted by the kernel to inform you that you tried to access the memory pointed by a `NULL` pointer.

Making that page inaccessible is the responsibility of the linker script that is read by the linker (`ld(1)`) with the "Memory map" of a process, and that reserves one page at address 0 to be unassigned by the kernel when loading the program.

Comment: Thanks Toby for the edit... I'd like to have better english than I have. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access address zero in virtual memory systems is that linker do not instruct the loader to map that page by default in the executable file. The reason is to trap errors. Prior to virtual memory systems, you could easily access address zero and NULL pointers were valid.

There are two approaches to making address 0 valid. The specific mechanics depend upon your system.

1. Instruct the linker to map address zero and make the first page WRITEABLE. Some linkers will allow you to do this. The method depends upon the linker.
2. Map address zero using system services as writeable at run time. The process here depends upon the operating system user.